# ElasticSearch: Exclude result which is scored 5 lower than the highest score

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

First of all, sorry for my bad English.

I'm very new to Elastic Search, and I want to filter query results by its scores.

What I'm trying to achieve is to remove results that are not intended to seek.

For example, let's say I have documents that storing field value for each document 'Comme des Garcons' and 'XXX des YYY'. And then when I search for 'Comme des', both resulted in. I want to exclude 'XXX des YYY' for this case because it's certain that a user does intend to seek 'Comme des Garcons'

I had tried to use a query that return items whole tokens are match, but I have to think about other cases like when people search for 'des'. In this case both have to appear in result because it is not certain which one is intended to seek.

So I thought how I can solve this and got an idea myself, and it was filtering results which have some amount of gap from its highest score.

But I don't know how to implement this to my query and it is a right way.

So my question is

1. Is my idea bad?
2. If not so bad, how to implement my idea to query?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: for what i know it's not trivial in elasticsearch. why not taking the top 3-4 results?

Comment: May you please provide your mapping and a couple of example documents? Which analyzers and other settings do you use?